# how do you replace every value in a list with another value?

Tags: python, list, python-3.x

I'm trying to make a text based hangman game. I have two lists:

- one with the word stored in it
- one to display '*' to replace letters from the other list.

I can check for the words in the first list and replace it, only if there is one occurrence.

For example: the word is 'DEAD' and the user inputs D. The output would then be D*** because it only finds one.

Current code to replace from one list to another list:

```
if guess() == True:
    pos = word.index(guessed)
    display[pos] = word[pos]
    print('Correct:  ', display)
```

How can i change the code so it replaces every occurrence in the list?

Comment: Possibly related: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/63833/guess-the-word-save-yourself-game/63971#63971

Answer (score 4):

You can use `zip` to compare the answer to the currently completed string letter-by-letter. Then use a generator expression within `join` to check if the letter was correct, otherwise don't change it. You'll still need to add logic to keep track of how hanged they are.

```
answer = 'dictionary'
current = '*'*len(answer)   # Produces '**********'

while current != answer:
    guess = input('guess a letter: ')
    current = ''.join(guess if guess == letter else blank for blank, letter in zip(current, answer))
    print(current, '\n')
```

Testing

```
guess a letter: i
*i**i*****

guess a letter: d
di**i*****

guess a letter: c
dic*i*****

guess a letter: t
dicti*****

guess a letter: n
dicti*n***

guess a letter: l  # Note this letter was wrong so the word didn't change
dicti*n***

guess a letter: o
diction***

guess a letter: r
diction*r*

guess a letter: a
dictionar*

guess a letter: y
dictionary
```

Comment: works perfectly. also thank you so much for quick response. but i need a loop or something to modify my code so that it will cycle through the current word checking for the answer then append onto the new list.

Answer (score 0):

```
word = "DEAD"

inp = "D"

print("".join([s if inp  == s else "_" for s in word]))
D__D
```

You should also use `if guess()` `if guess() == True`, if guess() will either be True or False if it retutns a boolean.

If you are using functions:

```
secret_word = "DEAD"


def is_guessed(secret_word, letters_guessed):
    return all(x in letters_guessed for x in secret_word)


def get_guessed_word(secret_word, guessed):
    return "".join([letter if letter in guessed else "_" for letter in secret_word])

letters_guessed = set()

guess = ""
lives = 5
while True:
    if is_guessed(secret_word,letters_guessed):
        print("Congratulations you guessed {}.".format(secret_word))
        break
    elif lives == 0:
        print("Out of lives the word was {}.".format(secret_word))
        break
    print("You have {} lives remaining".format(lives))
    inp = input("Enter a letter ").upper()
    if inp in letters_guessed:
        print("Already picked that letter")
        continue
    letters_guessed.add(inp)
    if inp.lower() in secret_word:
        print("Good guess")
        print(get_guessed_word(secret_word, letters_guessed))
    else:
        print("{} is not in the word".format(inp))
        lives -= 1
```

Comment: Technically does what OP asks, not what OP will want, as there is no memory, unlike Cyber's answer.

Comment: @OliverW., so setting the a variable = `"".join([s if inp  == s else "_" for s in word])`  and updating that will not do what the OP wants no?

Comment: No, no, don't get me wrong. Your answer is correct. But each time a guess is made, it will only reveal the position of *that specific guess* in the word. It won't show all the ones that have been guessed.

Comment: if possible i would like to change the current code. by adding a loop or something. instead of changing things from the input

Answer (score 0):

```
word = "dead" 
right_answer = set() #1

def replace_star(): # this part is relevant to your quesiton
    uncoverd = "" # first it makes a empty string
    for char in word: # loops trough every character in the word
        if char in right_answer: # if the character is in the set of right_answers
            uncoverd += char # it adds the character to the empty string
        else: # if is not 
            uncoverd += "*" # it add a '*'
    return uncoverd # returns the new word with all the character replaced with eiter a '*' or the guesses right character

score = 10
while True:
    uncoverd = replace_star()
    print ("Word:",uncoverd)
    answer = input("Guess one character of the word.\n>>")
    if answer in word: # 2
        print ("Spot on!")
        right_answer.add(answer) # 3
        if right_answer == set(word): # 4
            print ("You Win!")
            print ("The word was:", word)
            break
    else:
        score -= 1
        print ("Wrong")
        print ("Score: '%s'"%score)
        if score == 0:
            print ("You Lose!")
            break
```

By using a [set](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sets.html) you can check if all the unique items of a sequence are present in another

1. you create a empty set
2. check if the user input character is in the `word`
3. add this character to the `right_answer` set
4. check if the `right_answer` is equal a the set of characters in the word.